# Browserify cannot find xxx from yyy

Tags: npm, browserify, require, node-modules, tabulator

I am using a plugin called tabulator: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/quickstart
Here it is described how to install and require it:

```
npm install tabulator-tables --save  
var Tabulator = require('tabulator-tables');
```

This I have done, so far so good.
I put the require statement in a seperate js file called `main.js`
[image]
Then in order to be able to use require, I use browserify:

```
C:\SRC\cars\CARS\node_modules>browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Now I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'tabulator-tables' from 'C:\SRC\cars\CARS\node_modules'
    at C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-resolve\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:46:17
```

And I simply cannot understand what I am doing wrong!
Can anyone help me out with this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the 4.0.2 release over the weekend that accidentally removed the dist directory and is what is causing your problems. if you update to the 4.0.4 release your issue should be fixed

```
npm update tabulator-tables
```